# sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied - number detected by sqlite incorrect

Tags: python, sqlite, python-3.5

I know that there are many questions on the same subject, however, I haven't found the solution for my issue.

It is not a tuple issue by my knowledge.

I pass a tuple of 2 to a query with 2 questionmarks.
Sqlite says it only needs 1.

CODE:

```
def getRecipeId(categoryId, name):
  query = "SELECT id from tbl_recipes where name = '?' and categoryId = ?"
  result = sql.getOne(query, (name, int(categoryId)))
  print(result)

def getOne(query, parameters = ()):
  conn = sqlite3.connect(db.name)
  c = conn.cursor()
  print(query)
  print(parameters)
  c.execute(query, parameters)
  a = c.fetchone()
  return a
```

When I call getRecipeId(6,"SomeName"), I get as output:

```
SELECT id from tbl_recipes where name = '?' and categoryId = ?
('SomeName', 6)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Peter\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\bottle.py", line 862, in _handle
    return route.call(**args)
  File "C:\Users\Peter\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\bottle.py", line 1732, in wrapper
    rv = callback(*a, **ka)
  File "calculator.py", line 106, in finishEdit
    recipes.updateRecipe(categoryId, name, ingredientList)
  File "C:\Users\Peter\Documents\perso\costCalculator\recipes.py", line 40, in updateRecipe
    recId = getRecipeId(categoryId, name)
  File "C:\Users\Peter\Documents\perso\costCalculator\recipes.py", line 36, in getRecipeId
    result = sql.getOne(query, (name, int(categoryId)))
  File "C:\Users\Peter\Documents\perso\costCalculator\sql.py", line 59, in getOne
    c.execute(query, parameters)
sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 1, and there are 2 supplied.
```

I can't for the life of me detect what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Maybe remove the ' around the first ? and pass a string as first parameter?

Answer (score 1):

Don't put the placeholder in quotes.

```
query = "SELECT id from tbl_recipes where name = ? and categoryId = ?"
```